# Is there an implementation of the Altair light client?

Tags: light-clients, clients

its a bit unclear to me whether or not there exists an implementation of the Altair light client. i see the specs [here](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/altair/light-client/sync-protocol.md) but couldn't find the implementation. or is Altair meant to be implemented by the individual client implementations like Geth, Prysm, Lighthouse, etc?